# Hiding Columns in rhandsontable using css

Tags: html, css, r, rhandsontable

I am trying to hide columns in a `rhandsontable` rendered in a Shiny app. I believe that in the current version it can't be done as explained [here](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/249). However Handsontable does have a Hidden Columns [plugin](https://handsontable.com/docs/6.1.1/demo-hiding-columns.html). I am not conversant with how to add plugins. If someone can show me, that would be great.

I am trying a `css` based approach but that's also failing. In my `ui.R`, I render the table using `rHandsontableOutput("CargoListData")`. This table `CargoListData` has 19 columns and I wish to hide the 18th column. It's a timestamp that I don't wish to display to the user, but I do need it in calculations when the user edits the table and saves it.

I have been trying to hide the column using some `css` code in my `styles.css` file of the Shiny app :

```
#CargoListData > * > td:nth-child(18) {
    display: none;
}
```

However this has no effect on hiding the column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all else failed, here's something I discovered which handles this problem at least for now. My `rhandsontable` has 19 columns and I wish to hide the 17th to 19th columns. Specifying `colWidths` as 0.1 (and not 0) solves this.

```
hot_cols(colWidths = c(rep(150,16),rep(0.1,3)))
```